# Separating water and land in Sentinel-2 images using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am very new to the Google Earth Engine and found that it is a powerful tool in satellite images processing. I want to separate the land and water part in Sentinel-2 images and work only on the water part.

What should I do to solve this problem?

I am working with the image below:

```
var image= ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20210619T031541_20210619T032742_T48QYJ');
var visualization = {gain:'0.1,0.1,0.1',scale:5};
Map.addLayer(image,visualization,'1906');
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! As a new user, please take the Tour https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour Simply stating a problem and asking others to solve it is off topic. This is not a tutorial site. Please show what you've tried/where specifically you're stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sentinel 2A Data includes a Scene Classification (SCL) which already classifies the images in some very basic classes. Keep in mind, that this classification is in no way perfect, but it should give you a good and quick starting point.

To use it, you would mask the sentinel image by the appropriate value in the SCL. For the values see [this](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR#bands) page all the way at the bottom.

```
var image= ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20210619T031541_20210619T032742_T48QYJ');

var mask_land = image.updateMask(image.select('SCL').eq(6))

var visualization = {gain:'0.1,0.1,0.1',scale:5};
Map.addLayer(mask_land,visualization,'1906');
```

To mask it we first select the Scene Classification band and then build a binary mask, where every pixel that's equal to 6 (which is water) gets a one, and every pixel not equal to 6 gets a 0.